# Fortran error #8093: A do-variable within a DO body shall not appear in a variable definition context

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

I get this error when I compile my code in Fortran 2003:

```
error #8093: A do-variable within a DO body shall not appear in a variable definition context.
```

This is a part of my code:

```
 do k = v(i)-1, v(i)+1

     if (k == 0) then
        k= Nb
       end if

     if (k == Nb+1) then
        k=1
       end if
end do
```

`k` is consider as integer 
and

```
integer, dimension (10):: v=0
```

any body help me whats wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you exactly the problem: **you cannot *re-define* the loop variable `k` inside the do-loop**.

You probably want a second variable, e.g. `kk`, that does what you need it to do:

```
do k = v(i)-1, v(i)+1
 if (k == 0)    kk= Nb
 if (k == Nb+1) kk=1
end do
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to change the loop variable from within the loop. If you **really** want do to that, use something like:

```
! Infinite Loop
k = v(i)-1
do
  if ( k == 0 ) then
    k = Nb
  endif
  if ( k == Nb+1 ) then
    k = 1
  endif

  k = k + 1
  if ( k > v(i)+1 ) exit
enddo ! k
```